# BeamSql support for arrays and maps

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We pulled down the BeamSql code from the master branch on GitHub, since it seems to support Array, Map, and Row type fields. Does it have a way of querying those fields? or do we need to write UDFs for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to query them, see the examples in the tests:

- [arrays](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d110f6b7610b26edc1eb9a4b698840b21c151847/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/BeamSqlArrayTest.java#L236): `"SELECT f_stringArr[0] FROM PCOLLECTION"`;
- [nested rows and arrays](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d110f6b7610b26edc1eb9a4b698840b21c151847/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/BeamSqlDslNestedRowsTest.java#L272): `"SELECT PCOLLECTION.f_nestedRow.f_nestedArray[1] FROM PCOLLECTION"`;
- [maps](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d110f6b7610b26edc1eb9a4b698840b21c151847/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/BeamSqlMapTest.java#L131): `"SELECT f_intStringMap['key11'] FROM PCOLLECTION"`;

Caveats:

- you may need to fully qualify the fields;
- complex types support is under active development and there are known issues around it, e.g. [BEAM-4161](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4161) or [BEAM-4167](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4167);